# Forget password is working fine, but in change password, error: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined. Password value can not read

Tags: angular, aws-amplify

**Change password.ts**

```js
changePw(email: HTMLInputElement, contactNo: HTMLInputElement, username: HTMLInputElement, password: HTMLInputElement) {
  console.log("changepasswordhere");
  const user = {
    password: password.value,
    attributes: {
      email: email.value
    }
  }
  console.log(user)

  Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
    .then(user => {
      console.log("data " + user);
      this.toVerifyEmail = true;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  // console.log(user)
}
```

**Change password.html**

```html
<label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Username</label>
<!-- <input type="text" required (keypress)="numberOnly($event)" id="confirmationcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirmation Code"  [(ngModel)]="confirmationcode" name="confirmationform" required autofocus> -->
<input
  type="number"
  class="form-control"
  id="exampleInputverifycode1"
  aria-describedby="verifyCodeHelp"
  placeholder="Enter the code"
  #verifycode
/>
<input
  type="password"
  id="inputPassword"
  class="form-control"
  placeholder="New Password"
  [(ngModel)]="newpassword"
  name="loginform"
  required
  autofocus
/>
<input
  type="password"
  id="inputPassword"
  class="form-control"
  placeholder="Confirm New Password"
  [(ngModel)]="confirmpassword"
  name="loginform"
  required
  autofocus
/>
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="message" role="alert">
  {{message}}
</div>

<button
  class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
  (click)="changePw(email,password,username,contactNo)"
>
  Submit
</button>
```

In forget password, enter the user name and cognito will check about the name name existence, then it send OTP. After that in change password user have to enter OTP to verify, new and confirm new password.As I am very new in aws-amplify, plz can anyone give me advise here.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML you are binding two of your input fields by [(ngModel] to password variables:

```html
<input
  type="password"
  id="inputPassword"
  class="form-control"
  placeholder="New Password"
  [(ngModel)]="newpassword"
  name="loginform"
  required
  autofocus
/>
<input
  type="password"
  id="inputPassword"
  class="form-control"
  placeholder="Confirm New Password"
  [(ngModel)]="confirmpassword"
  name="loginform"
  required
  autofocus
/>
```

In your typescript file you should therefor have two variables: newpassword and confirmpassword. This is what the ngModel will interact with to keep them update to date to whatever the user entered in the input field.

Finally, if you already have those two in your typescript, you can use it in your changePw function like so:

```js
changePw(email: HTMLInputElement, contactNo: HTMLInputElement, username: HTMLInputElement, password: HTMLInputElement) {
  console.log("changepasswordhere");
  const user = {
    // edited here: use your already existing variable
    password: newpassword,
    attributes: {
      email: email.value
    }
  }
  console.log(user)

  Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
    .then(user => {
      console.log("data " + user);
      this.toVerifyEmail = true;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  // console.log(user)
}
```

You would want to check if the newpassword and the confirmpassword are equal, but this is one way you could go.

Comment: hi gerstams, thanks for reply. But I want to ask how to use those variables confirm new password and new password under of password property? Like 
`password: newpassword,
password: confirmpassword`

Comment: `changePw(email: HTMLInputElement, contactNo: HTMLInputElement, username: HTMLInputElement, newpassword: HTMLInputElement,confirmnewpassword: HTMLInputElement) {
    console.log("changepasswordhere");
    const user = {
      password: newpassword,confirmnewpassword,
      attributes: {
        email: email.value
      }
    }
    console.log(user.password)`

Comment: Please make an update to your question then ;-) That also keeps to keep the code clean as comments squeeze the code